# My eclipse plugin is showing on eclipse marketplace web site, but not in eclipse marketplace client

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, eclipse-marketplace

I uploaded a plugin I developped to eclipse marketplace platform, following the steps described at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/quickstart.

Now I can find my plugin on their web site (https://marketplace.eclipse.org), and I can install it from there (by dragging and dropping the install button).

The problem is I can't find it using eclipse marketplace client (the one inside eclipse, that opens using Help / Eclipse Marketplace...).

What could be wrong...? Maybe the development stage (now beta) ? Maybe eclipse compatible versions have to be specified ? (I said luna but maybe there is a format or something)

I have not put links to my plugin because I wasn't sure about SO policy. I can put them / send them by mail if it can be helpful.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Well it works now !

I changed several things so I'm not sure which one was the good one :
- Changed development stage from "alpha" to "beta"
- Added a version for the plugin ("1.1.0", this is just a text field)
- Added a version for eclipse ("Luna", this is just a text field)

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing information was the Eclipse version. Without that, the Marketplace Client in your Eclipse install doesn't know if the connector is compatible with that version of Eclipse.

For example, the [JBoss Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools) and [Red Hat Developer Studio](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/red-hat-jboss-developer-studio/) marketplace connectors have several different versions of tooling in it, each targeting a different version of Eclipse.

- 4.5 / 11 -> Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)
- 4.4 / 10 -> Eclipse Neon (4.6)
- 4.3 / 9 -> Eclipse Mars (4.4)
- 4.2 / 8 -> Eclipse Luna (4.3)

So, depending on the version of Eclipse you're using, you'll get a different version of tooling from the connector, as it links to a different update site for each version.

[image: devstudio 11 section of marketplace connector]
[image: devstudio 10 section of marketplace connector]